# How to write multiple conditions in one line

Tags: python

Is there a way that we can add multiple conditions in a single line? this is not working atm, but if it were separated into different sequences, it would work.

Just to mention, I used and/or and still not working

```py
    user_input = remove_punct(user_input), remove_spaces(user_input), user_input.lower
    return user_input
```

[image]

Comment: when you seperated into seperate stages are you storing the output from each function and passing that as the input to the next function?

Comment: `remove_spaces(remove_punct(user_input.lower()))`

Comment: Please post *text*, not images (as instructed in the guidance).  Aside, these will need to be separate function calls, as they are not members of the returned type’s class; unless you nest the calls; but do so carefully.  Additionally, the call to `lower` must be called as `lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just nest all the operations! Your approach doesn't work as a tuple is being created on the right hand side and the value of `user_input` doesn't get updated.

Try this

```
user_input = remove_punct(remove_spaces(user_input.lower()))
```

Edit:
As pointed out by @S3DEV, the above solution assumes that the functions `remove_punct`, `remove_spaces` return the updated value of the input after performing the operation

Comment: Unless one of the functions returns `None` or another ‘unexpected’ value, which the receiving function is not designed to handle in a controlled way.    Could cause the program to crash and burn.  Perhaps add a cautionary statement to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of your functions you want to use, and then iterate over them storing the result back into the input string. Alternativly if your functions are just using string methods then you can just keep chaining them. Lastly if you want to chain them like in string but need your own methods you could write your own class.

```py
def remove_space(some_string: str):
    return some_string.strip()


def remove_punct(some_string: str):
    return some_string.replace("!", "")


def clean(some_string):
    functions = remove_space, remove_punct, str.lower
    for fun in functions:
        some_string = fun(some_string)
    return some_string

def clean2(some_string: str):
    return some_string.strip().replace("!", "").lower()

print(clean("   hello world!  "))
print(clean2("   hello world!  "))
```